# Windows batch equivalent to bash's &

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I'm working on a server in java that will eventually run on linux, but I'm also need to test it on windows.

The server, when needed, should start a new process for a client (also in java). During the tests, I dont want to run executable jar files, but only the classpath.

So currently (on windows), I start a new process that runs a batch file with parameters, that in it's turn runs the command: `java -cp bin MyClass %*`.

My problem is, that I want to wait till the batch finishes its run in order to record any errors in the batch file, but once it has started, I need it to run the Class (the client) without waiting.

In linux it should have been as simple as just adding `&` at the end of the command.. But how to do it in windows?

I have treid running the command with `start "" "java -cp bin MyClass %*"` but I got an error.
And `call java -cp bin MyClass %*` did the same thing as without the `call`.

Am I missing something here?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't put executable for `start` into quotes, only the title needs that: `start "Java" java -cp bin MyClass %*`

Comment: It throws an error:

"windows cannot find 'java -cp bin MyClass ....'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

Comment: Then you need to put `java.exe` into your `PATH` (or use a fully qualified name)

Comment: Ok, it appears that the java on PATH was an outdated java version.. I've updated it, and it works now. Thanks!!!



But another question if you have the time: how can i keep the window that is opened by the `start` comman open after the process is finished?

Thanks again!!

Comment: Put a pause at the end of the batch file. or `start "" /w cmd /k java etc`